Can nonlocal be used to repeatedly reference names in higher levels of scope?
In Python, the nonlocal keyword allows code in an inner scope to access a name in the enclosing scope.
To explain this, we can observe the behaviour of this example code, taken from the Python tutorial documentation.
def scope_test():
    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = 'nonlocal spam'
    spam = 'test spam'
    do_nonlocal()
    print(f'after nonlocal assignment spam={spam}')

scope_test()
# prints: 'after nonlocal assignment spam=nonlocal spam'

This demonstrates that the nonlocal keyword can be used to access the name spam from the enclosing scope, rather than the scope defined by do_nonlocal.
Can nonlocal be used repeatedly to access progressively higher levels of scope?

The answer is yes. Before providing a demonstration example, it is helpful to annotate some code to show where the various scopes exist.
# global scope exists here

def spam_function():
    # the function definition `spam_function` creates a new "local"
    # scope with the same name

    def inner_spam_function():
        # this function definition creates yet another scope, with
        # the name `inner_spam_function`. this scope/namespace is
        # nested within the `spam_function` (enclosing) scope

        def inner_inner_spam_function():
            # finally, yet another level of nested function
            # this namespace `inner_inner_spam_function` lives inside
            # global/spam_function/inner_spam_function/inner_inner_spam_function

It is useful to know that a function definition itself creates a new level of scope. (A new namespace.) Namespaces in Python are essentially a tree type data structure.
Finally, here is the demonstration example:
def spam_function():
    spam = 'spam function spam'

    def inner_spam_function():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = 'inner spam function'

        def inner_inner_spam_function():
            nonlocal spam
            spam = 'inner inner spam function - wow'

        inner_inner_spam_function()
    inner_spam_function()
    print(f'spam={spam}')

spam_function()
# this will print: `spam=inner inner spam function - wow`

The nonlocal keyword will cause names to be resolved in progressively higher levels of non-local scope until a match is found, not just the immediate level above. This can be seen with the following example:
def spam_function():
    spam = 'spam function spam'

    def inner_spam_function():
        pass

        def inner_inner_spam_function():
            nonlocal spam
            spam = 'inner inner spam function - wow'

        inner_inner_spam_function()
    inner_spam_function()
    print(f'spam={spam}')

spam_function()
# this will print: `spam=inner inner spam function - wow`

Finally, it might be useful to note that without nonlocal, assignment creates a new name, whereas reading a value looks in the enclosing scope(s) to resolve the name.
def outer_function():
    x = 10

    def inner_function_with_assignment():
        x = 11 # writing creates a new name `x`

    inner_function_with_assignment()
    print(x)
    # prints 10

    def inner_function_with_read():
        y = x # x is resolved to x in scope 1 level higher
        print(y)

    inner_function_with_read()
    # prints 10

    def nested_inner_function_with_read_1():
        def nested_inner_function_with_read_2():
            z = x # x is resolved to x in scope 2 levels higher
            print(z)
        nested_inner_function_with_read_2()

    nested_inner_function_with_read_1()
    # prints 10

outer_function()


This has nothing to do with recursion, though, just independent variables reusing the same name in different scopes.

To clarify: nonlocal spam in inner_inner_spam_function says that spam should not declare a local variable spam, but use the next higher up spam which already exists. Since inner_spam_function doesn't declare a spam variable (because it does the same thing), the next higher up function which does declare spam is spam_function. If you omitted any mention of spam from inner_spam_function, you'd have the same effect.
